# SELECT value WHERE IN SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following two tables:

```
 users: id | nickname | phone
 phonebook: id | ownerid | phone | name
```

Nickname and phone are both indexes and varchars, ownerid is index too.

Table phonebook contains contact lists of given user, i.e.: `1, 1, '+12345678','Jimmy'`

All I need is to find all user nicknames who are located in phonebook of ownerId.

I tried following: `SELECT u.nickname FROM users u WHERE u.phone IN (SELECT pb.phone FROM phonebook pb WHERE pb.ownerid=1)`

But it always returns empty set.

**Example data**

```
users
1 | josh | +380123456789
2 | jimmy | +12345678
3 | vladimir | +421987123456
phonebook
1 | 1 | +12345678 | Jimmy Surname
2 | 1 | +12567321 | Anne (This user isn't registered in this service / users)
3 | 1 | +421987123456 | Vladimir Novak
4 | 3 | +3556233455 | Julia
```

So basically I need to return `jimmy,vladimir` because they exist both in phonebook of user 1 (`ownerid=1`) and users table.

Comment: Is phonebook's `ownerid`  linked to users' `id` field? If so, it would be nice if it was called `userid` and if so, simply join both tables by these fields.

Comment: yes, ownerid is basically id of user

Comment: `SELECT u.nickname FROM users u INNER JOIN phonebook pb ON u.id = pb.ownerid`

Comment: ah, that returns two records for nickname of ownerid, wait I will edit post to provide more detail with example data

Comment: provided example data

Comment: So simply because someone's first name is Jimmy you are 100% sure it must be the one 'jimmy' in the users table? Wow!

Comment: No, because his phone number is same as in user table

Comment: just to make it clear, usage case: user uploads his phonebook to server and server sends him nicknames of real users back who are in his phone book

Comment: Ah, okay, so its no coincidence that Jimmy's phone number is the same, and the phone number difference for Vladimir is a typo. Yes?

Comment: ah yes, typo, I wrote it quick, I fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to select nicknames from users:

```
select nickname
from users
```

You only want to select records where the phone number is in the set of friends of user 1:

```
where phone in
(
  select phone
  from phonebook
  where ownerid = 1
)
```

Combined:

```
select nickname
from users
where phone in
(
  select phone
  from phonebook
  where ownerid = 1
);
```

Comment: Interestingly, OP attempted same query!

Comment: @Parfait: Haha, as it was mentioned the query didn't work, I didn't really look at it. Embarrassing :-| Yes, it's the same query. So something else is wrong. Maybe additional blanks in the phone numbers.

Comment: embrassing, yes, seems that's case, some numbers don't have '+' signs o_o, but yes, this is correct answer anyway